# How to use native google maps with ionic4 application?

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using native google maps plugin version 5.5.0 with ionic4 app. Unfortunately not getting success. I can only see white/transparent screen instead of map. I've tried all solutions provided by stack overflow but no success. Please help me sort this issue. I've been stuck on this since last seven days.

my home.html code

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 80%;">
    <ion-button ion-button (click)="onButtonClick()">Demo</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

my .ts file

```
    import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  Marker,
  GoogleMapsAnimation,
  MyLocation,
  LatLng
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';
ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready();
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
    this.goToMyLocation();
  }

goToMyLocation() {
    this.map.clear();

    // Get the location of you
    this.map.getMyLocation().then((location: MyLocation) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null, 2));

      // Move the map camera to the location with animation
      this.map.animateCamera({
        target: location.latLng,
        zoom: 17,
        duration: 5000
      });

      //add a marker
      let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        title: '@ionic-native/google-maps plugin!',
        snippet: 'This plugin is awesome!',
        position: location.latLng,
        animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.BOUNCE
      });

      //show the infoWindow
      marker.showInfoWindow();

      //If clicked it, display the alert
      marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
        this.showToast('clicked!');
      });

      this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log("Click MAP", data);
        }
      );
    })
      .catch(err => {
        //this.loading.dismiss();
        this.showToast(err.error_message);
      });
  }
```

my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "aetabs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "adaept",
  "homepage": "https://aetabs.adaept.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ionic serve",
    "build": "ionic build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.45",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "an": "0.0.8",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.2",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^1.2.2",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "typescript": "~3.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An adaept project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "my-API-key",
        "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "my-API-key",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try demo : https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4

Comment: thank you for quick response. I've tried this demo also but no success.

Comment: what is the error or warning you are getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in console. and my API key is also paid key.

Comment: Please share relevant parts of your code. The package.json tells us very little about how you implemented it in your code.

Comment: I've edited my question. With more code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me to solve my problem. I can see the map instead of blank or gray screen with only google logo.

Step 1) Remove ionic google maps plugin

Step 2) Remove Platform

Step 3) Create new API key

Step 4) Add plugin with New API key for ex. ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="(new api key here)" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="(new api key here)"

Step 5) Add platform

Step 6) Run ionic app for ex. ionic cordova run android/ios